# Iterating the values of a submake

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to automate some commands I use regularly in a Makefile, but I can't seem to figure out the right syntax for it.

Given the following targets:

```
.PHONY: params-list
params-list:
    @aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --path /${SERVICE}/${ENV} | jq -c -r '.Parameters[] | .Name'

.PHONY: params-get
params-get:
    @aws ssm get-parameter --name ${PARAM} --with-decryption | jq -c -r .Parameter.Value
```

I was attempting to call `params-list` and then feed the results into `params-get`. My best attempt was along the lines of:

```
.PHONY: params
params:
    for param in $(MAKE) params-list; do \
        $(MAKE) params-get PARAM=$${param}; \
    done
```

But obviously doesn't work. What's the right way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One hint is to eschew shell constructs for *make* ones. Going one step at a time here.

For the *get* operation, we encode one target for each param. So for param `p1` (say), we invent a target `params-get<p1>`. We note that inside the recipe (i.e., the shell commands) that `$@` will expand to `params-get<p1>`. Therefore `${@:params-get<%>=%}` will expand to `p1`.

Writing this out in *make* syntax:

```
.PHONY: params-get<p1>
params-get<p1>:
      @aws ssm get-parameter --name ${@:params-get<%>=%} --with-decryption | jq -c -r .Parameter.Value
```

I note that with an intermediate variable we can have exactly the same recipe you used in your earlier incantation.

```
PARAM = ${@:params-get<%>=%}

.PHONY: params-get<p1>
params-get<p1>:
      @aws ssm get-parameter --name ${PARAM} --with-decryption | jq -c -r .Parameter.Value
```

If we have a second param `pa` (say), that's easy to add:

```
PARAM = ${@:params-get<%>=%}

.PHONY: params-get<p1> params-get<pa>
params-get<p1> params-get<pa>:
      @aws ssm get-parameter --name ${PARAM} …
```

I hope you can see some boiler plate appearing here.

Moving towards some more dynamically generated *make*, rather than hard-coding each param, let's put all the possible params in a list called `$PARAMS`

```
PARAMS := p1 pa another
get-targets := ${PARAMS:%=params-get<%>}

PARAM = ${@:params-get<%>=%}

.PHONY: ${get-targets}
${get-targets}:
      @aws ssm get-parameter --name ${PARAM} …

.PHONY: params-get
params-get: ${get-targets}
      echo $@ Done
```

I have added your original `params-get` target. Now all the work is done by dependencies.

- No shell loop in sight.
- The exit code of each `aws ssm get-parameter` is checked by make.
- The code is parallel safe: *make -j9* will run 9 jobs in parallel until the work is exhausted. Nice if you have 8 CPUs. (If your *make* is not parallel safe then it is *broken* by the way.)

We are pretty close now. We just have to ensure `$PARAMS` is set to the output of `ssm get-parameters-by-path`.

Something like:

```
.PHONY: params-list
params-list:
    @aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --path /${SERVICE}/${ENV} | jq -c -r '.Parameters[] | .Name'

PARAMS := $(shell ${MAKE} params-list)
get-targets := ${PARAMS:%=params-get<%>}

PARAM = ${@:params-get<%>=%}

.PHONY: ${get-targets}
${get-targets}:
      @aws ssm get-parameter --name ${PARAM} --with-decryption | jq -c -r .Parameter.Value

.PHONY: params-get
params-get: ${get-targets}
      echo $@ Done
```

Definitely not a fan of using `$(shell …)`, but this is just a sketch.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a single (long) target/recipe as follows:

```
.PHONY: params-get
params-get:
    @for p in $$(aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --path /${SERVICE}/${ENV} | jq -c -r '.Parameters[] | .Name'); do \
        aws ssm get-parameter --name $$p --with-decryption | jq -c -r .Parameter.Value; \
     done
```

This assumes that your parameters don't have white spaces in them

------------  EDIT ---------------

To be able to access the parameters in another recipe, you can create a rule to create a file with the list of files in one recipe, and then access that file in another recipe as so:

```
# note that in this case .params-list is actually the name of a file,
# but it is declared as phony to force it to be rebuilt every time.
.PHONY: .params-list
.params-list:
    aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --path /${SERVICE}/${ENV} | jq -c -r '.Parameters[] | .Name' > $@

.PHONY: params-get
params-get: .params-list
    @for param in $$(cat .params-list); do \
       aws ssm get-parameter --name $${param} --with-decryption | jq -c -r .Parameter.Value; \
     done;
```

Comment: That does work indeed. Is it possible to do some form of target composition with a loop though? Mostly so I may reuse the targets elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, you can do this by outputting to a file in one recipe, and then importing the file in the other recipe.   I'll edit the answer with this solution as well.